# Drag and drop into a browser application

Tags: browser, drag-and-drop

We have a browser based application written in PHP in which I want to drag-n-drop files from the windows explorer or directly email attachments(this would be very cool). On dropping the files in the browser application, it should save it on a particular folder on the server. Any help on how this can be achieved would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JS or HTML5 would seem to be your best bets. But I have had trouble with d&d in MSIE (FF was ok). The downside is that HTML is not scheduled to be finalized until 2022(!) - you can expect support before then (even today), but it may not be consistent.

There is a good HTML demo here http://ljouanneau.com/lab/html5/demodragdrop.html

This will also allow you to d&d stuff from the browser to the PC (bi-directional)

I don't do JS so can't help you there, sorry (I'm a PHP guy too ;-)